# How do you take the reciprocal of a vector?

Tags: c#, vector, physics

I am working in C# and I am trying to figure out how to take the reciprocal of the vector velocity.

I tried:

```
Vector2 Velocity;

Vector2 Reciprocal = 1 / Velocity;
```

But I cannot do this because I cannot take an int and divide it by a vector. I have tried to look for an answer to this, but I have not fared well...

Comment: Is this a custom vector-type under your control? The one from XNA? Something else?

Comment: What does the reciprocal of a vector mean?

Comment: @Ani - I am using Visual Studio with XNA.

Comment: @Gabe: I imagine the OP wants a new vector with the individual components being reciprocals of the original.

Comment: @Ani: I was thinking normal, but your guess is as good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vector2 Velocity
Vector2 Reciprocal
Reciprocal.X = Reciprocal.Y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((1.0/Velocity.Length()),2)/2)
```

Comment: Wishing extension operator coming soon

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically speaking, the reciprocal of a vector is not well-defined.  You can take the reciprocal of the *magnitude* of a vector, and you can create a new vector whose components are the reciprocals of the components of the original vector, but the notion of the reciprocal of a vector itself isn't meaningful.

Depending on which operation you want to do, the code will be different.

Comment: I just want the magnitude, because the direction does not matter to me for this problem.

Comment: @Ryan Then you don't want the reciprocal _of a vector_ , which, as templatetypedef wrote, is not defined.

Comment: In any application I can think of, the vector would stay pointing the same direction and you just divide by the magnitude. It's true that you can't "divide by a vector" although you actually can with directional derivative, but the reciprocal of a vector can be commonly understood as `1/mag * unit vec pointing in the original direction`. I think this even appears in Stewart.

Comment: @Lao Tsu- I have not seen this notation before.  I see why it might be intuitive, but since a Google search for "reciprocal vector" turns up pages primarily pertaining to lattice cryptography, I'm not sure that it's standardized.